# How do I change the UIimageview image in the ViewController when the side menu is clicked?

Tags: swift, tableview, side-menu, vip

I want to change the background image in the Viewcontroller when one of the side menu items is clicked.

I am using VIP architecture while doing this process.

When the item on the side menu is clicked, the following code block works:

```
  else if indexPath.row == 1

    {
        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            print("Any ")
            print(indexPath)
        case 1:
            print("Dark Mode ")
          //  self.interactor?.selectThemes(theme: "Dark")
            
            router?.changeTheme(theme: .Dark)
            

        case 2:
            print("Once a day ")
            
        default:
            print("out of range")
        }
    }
```

then there is something I want to do on the router:

```
func changeTheme(theme:Themes){
    if Themes.Dark == theme
    {
       var jokegenerate = JokeGenerateController()
        
        jokegenerate.changeBackground(image: UIImage(named: "duck")!)
       
        //print(theme)
        
    }
```

}

Finally, I want to change the image in the viewController. my code is below:

```
  func changeBackground(image: UIImage){
    backGroundImage.image = image
    print("hey")
}
```

But I am getting the following error here:
*Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value*

What should I do to fix the error?

Comment: does the image named "duck" exists in your assets? else, is backGroundImage connected to your view controller in storyboard?

Comment: @Alastar I have an image named "duck" in Asset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check this link [(delegate)](https://learnappmaking.com/delegation-swift-how-to/)

You should create connections between modules.

```
class Bakery
{
    var delegate:BakeryDelegate?

    func makeCookie()
    {
        var cookie = Cookie()
        cookie.size = 6
        cookie.hasChocolateChips = true

        delegate?.cookieWasBaked(cookie)
    }
}

class CookieShop: BakeryDelegate
{
    func cookieWasBaked(_ cookie: Cookie)
    {
        print("Yay! A new cookie was baked, with size \(cookie.size)")
    }
}
let shop = CookieShop()

let bakery = Bakery()
bakery.delegate = shop

bakery.makeCookie()
```

Something like that.